# How do I put lists side by side also without using ljust/rjust

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

As of now this is what my code looks like (It is not fully finished but to continue on this I would like to get the structure down first) :

(Also more text below)

def Main():

```
city = ['City', '________________', 'Boston', 'Montreal', 'Toronto', 'Detroit', 'Mackinaw City', 'Sault Ste. Marie', 'Wawa', 'Marathon', 'Thunder Bay', 'Duluth', 'Minneapolis', 'Fargo', 'Winnipeg', 'Regina', 'Swift Current', 'Medicine Hat', 'Calgary', 'Great Falls', 'Butte', 'Spokane', 'Seattle', 'Vancouver']
for items in city:
    a = items
    while len(a) < 16:
        a += " "
    
state = ['State/Province', '________________', 'Massachusetts', 'Quebec', 'Ontario', 'Michigan', 'Michigan', 'Ontario', 'Ontario', 'Ontario', 'Ontario', 'Minnesota', 'Minnesota', 'North Dakota', 'Manitoba', 'Saskatachewan', 'Saskatachewan', 'Alberta', 'Alberta', 'Montana', 'Montana', 'Washington', 'Washington', 'British Columbia']
for items in state:
    b = items
    while len(b) < 16:
        b += " "
    
miles = [0, 310, 335, 237, 292, 53, 132, 116, 169, 191, 156, 237, 218, 357, 156, 144, 191, 278, 155, 318, 282, 168]
for items in miles:
    c = items
    kilometers = [c * 1.609344 for c in miles]

    
liters = [35.56, 36.23, 24.26, 32.29, 6.47, 14.27, 12.91, 17.77, 20.67, 18.89, 28.96, 25.78, 37.54, 20.36, 17.58, 22.59, 30.74, 19.57, 35.13, 32.37, 21.19]
for items in liters:
    d = items
    gallons = [d * 3.785411784 for d in liters]

    print (a,b,c,d)
```

When I do this and run the program it turns out like this:

```
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 35.56
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 36.23
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 24.26
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 32.29
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 6.47
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 14.27
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 12.91
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 17.77
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 20.67
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 18.89
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 28.96
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 25.78
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 37.54
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 20.36
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 17.58
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 22.59
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 30.74
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 19.57
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 35.13
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 32.37
Vancouver        British Columbia 168 21.19
```

and what I really need for it to look like is:

```
Boston          Massachusetts      0        0      0   
Montreal        Quebec           310    40.05  35.56  L
Toronto         Ontario          335    41.55  36.23  L                                                                      
Detroit         Michigan         237    17.05   6.41  G
Mackinaw City   Michigan         292    23.62   8.53  G
Sault Ste. MarieOntario           53     7.79   6.47  L
Wawa            Ontario          132    16.70  14.27  L
Marathon        Ontario          116    15.37  12.91  L
Thunder Bay     Ontario          169    20.38  17.77  L
Duluth          Minnesota        191    14.16   5.46  G
Minneapolis     Minnesota        156    13.17   4.99  G
Fargo           North Dakota     237    20.02   7.65  G
Winnepeg        Manitoba         218    26.94  25.78  L
Regina          Saskatchewan     357    41.80  37.54  L
Swift Current   Saskatchewan     156    23.67  20.36  L
Medicine Hat    Alberta          144    18.63  17.58  L
Calgary         Alberta          191    25.46  22.59  L
Great Falls     Montana          278    21.95   8.12  G
Butte           Montana          155    13.53   5.17  G
Spokane         Washington       318    24.68   9.28  G
Seattle         Washington       282    22.94   8.55  G
Vancouver       British Columbia 168    24.70  21.19  L
```

I just am not good with Python and I feel like an idiot so if someone could help me with this issue that would be fantastic.

Comment: Absolutely, it's I tried to post a photo but it didn't allow me cause I just made this account

Comment: the actual answer is a PDF that I can't copy and paste, it is blurred out but you can see the examples. I fixed it anyways. Thank you tho.

Comment: You can't use 4 separate loops.  You need to be reading those lists in parallel, like `for a,b,c,d in zip(city, state, miles, liters):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
city = ['City', '________________', 'Boston', 'Montreal', 'Toronto', 'Detroit', 'Mackinaw City', 'Sault Ste. Marie', 'Wawa', 'Marathon', 'Thunder Bay', 'Duluth', 'Minneapolis', 'Fargo', 'Winnipeg', 'Regina', 'Swift Current', 'Medicine Hat', 'Calgary', 'Great Falls', 'Butte', 'Spokane', 'Seattle', 'Vancouver']

state = ['State/Province', '________________', 'Massachusetts', 'Quebec', 'Ontario', 'Michigan', 'Michigan', 'Ontario', 'Ontario', 'Ontario', 'Ontario', 'Minnesota', 'Minnesota', 'North Dakota', 'Manitoba', 'Saskatachewan', 'Saskatachewan', 'Alberta', 'Alberta', 'Montana', 'Montana', 'Washington', 'Washington', 'British Columbia']
    
miles = [0, 310, 335, 237, 292, 53, 132, 116, 169, 191, 156, 237, 218, 357, 156, 144, 191, 278, 155, 318, 282, 168]
    
liters = [35.56, 36.23, 24.26, 32.29, 6.47, 14.27, 12.91, 17.77, 20.67, 18.89, 28.96, 25.78, 37.54, 20.36, 17.58, 22.59, 30.74, 19.57, 35.13, 32.37, 21.19]

for a,b,c,d in zip(city, state, miles, liters):
    while len(a) < 16:
        a += " "
    while len(b) < 16:
        b += " "
    kilometers = c * 1.609344

    gallons = d * 3.785411784

    print (a,b,c,d)
```